# List index out of range. However I can print the list index that I want to use

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to access an indexed item in a list within a dictionary. The dictionary has two keys, the first being an id key, and then each id has an associated dictionary with a datetime object as the key.

I am filtering through the dictionary as I have done many times before in my code and have a peculiar "list index out of range" error. I know that python starts indexing at 0 and have taken this into account.

I am trying to access the 5th element in a list when I get this error. However if I insert the python debugger into my code I am then able to print this same indexed element that produced the error.

[An image of the command prompt when I try to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7aum.png)

```
def plot_histogram(dict, newpath):
norm_res = []
res = [] # should I also plot a histogram of the residual?
for id in dict:
    for dt in dict[id]:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if dict[id][dt][5] is not None: # np.nan
            norm_res.append(float(dict[id][dt][5])) # Need to exclud None results. But want to exclude them for both 
                                                    # norm res and res at the same time so that neither result is skewed 
            res.append(float(dict[id][dt][4]))      # unfailry. (?)
f = plt.figure()
sns.distplot(norm_res)
f.savefig(newpath + r'\sns_norm_res_histogram.png', dpi=500)
g = plt.figure()
sns.distplot(res)
g.savefig(newpath + r'\sns_res_histogram.png', dpi=500)
return
```

I think the error could be to do with the fact that I am trying to access the last element in the list, and sometimes this element is a None type. Does this mean that the list will be shortened in length when the None element is in the last position?

Thank you in advance foe any help.

Comment: Well, there is no `dict[id][dt][5])`, you must check the code that produces your dict. Note that `dict` is a bad choice for a variable name, as it is a Python builtin.

Comment: Why does it let me print dict[id][dt][5] (see linked photo in post)? @ThierryLathuille

Comment: If you want to include the prompt, you should edit it into the question. We usually don't download external content.

Comment: You check for not None, but you don't check to see if it is a list of sufficient length. What was the value of the list when you got the error? You spent a lot of time typing in a question when a simple breakpoint would have answered this.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `dict[id][dt][5]` for *some* `id` and *some* `dt` does not exist. The one you are able to print when debugging likely has a different `id` or `dt`.

Comment: wouldn't that give KeyError?

Comment: That would happen if `dict[id]` or `dict[id][dt]` did not exist. `dict[id][dt][5]` refers to a list within a dict of dicts.